# Using docker service to apply rolling update to tensorflow serving models

Tags: docker, tensorflow, docker-compose, tensorflow-serving

I have a `docker-compose.yml` that looks like the following. It takes a tensorflow `.pb` model and deploys an API:

```
version: "3"
services:
  api:
    image: tensorflow/serving:1.14.0-rc0
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
    ports:
      - "8501:8501"
    networks:
      - webnet
    volumes:
      - source:target
    environment:
        - MODEL_NAME=model_name
networks:
  webnet:
```

Following the tensorflow serving instruction, the source folder has the following structure:

```
- source 
  - 1
    - variables
    - model.rb
```

I can successfully run this file with `docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml service-name`.

Let's say that now, I have version 2 of the model, and I would like to apply a rolling update to switch from version 1 to version 2 without killing the current process.

```
- source 
  - 1
    - variables
    - model.rb
  - 2
    - variables
    - model.rb
```

What is the command that I need to run here? I'm assuming that I need to use `docker service update` somehow, but I was not sure the safest way to do this.